# Importing Blogger blog to WordPress

Tags: xml, wordpress, import, blogger, data-import

So I have this big (400MB) xml file I exported from my Blogger blog.
I import it the WordPress blog hosted by Wordpress.com through the interface.
There is a text saying upload limited to 15mb but it doesn't seem to cause a problem.

After I select and upload the file there is a message saying "Upload successful, Please give us some time to import the data".

But nothing happens.

I could not find anything on the internet, and there are no errors messages to guide me...
I've tried the procedure more that 3 times.

Anyone have any idea of whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should convert that XML file to a WXR using this [tool](http://blogger2wordpress.appspot.com/). Then you should take the WXR and split it into multiple parts at 15MB each using this tool, the [WXR File Splitter](http://rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/). It is most likely not importing because you are not respecting the file size upload input.

OR

You should use the [Blogger to WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer/) plugin, because this is what it was designed for. You just log into your Blogger account, then you select which blog you want to import, and it takes over the rest.

Comment: Is there any new alternative to this tool that you are aware of? I am REALLY, REALLY struggling to get my XML file imported without breaking it down.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a friend who needed to import a large Blogger export into WordPress so I wrote an ad-hoc importer and then decided to refactor it to work as a WordPress plugin.

At this point in time it is not fully working but a PHP developer would be able to make it work as it is 95% there.  I hope to fix it to make it actually work within the next week, so if you are reading this after August 2016 *hopefully* it will be workable, at least for common use-cases:

- https://github.com/mikeschinkel/wp-large-blogger-import