# Importing to Wordpress from Blogger with original resolution images

Tags: wordpress, image, png, blogger

I reviewed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616852/importing-blogger-blog-to-wordpress) but the plugin page for the solution says it is behind by 3 major WP versions.

Decided to move blog from Blogger to Wordpress because Blogger was downsampling my graphs/plots which made them unacceptably blurry.

Got everything into Wordpress, BUT it appears Blogger exported the blog with links to the downsampled images. The media library in Wordpress has two files for every image - one for the original resolution and one for the blurry image Blogger created:[image]

The first file is the Blogger-created version and that is what the post links to. I have hundreds of graphs like this.

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this short of manually editing links? Is there a way to force Blogger to export the posts as I created them, with links to the original files I uploaded? That would be ideal.

Part 2: I probably have 110 (or 161) posts where the images are still being served up from Blogger! Via custom links - [mouse-over the image in the example here](https://datatellsme.com/2018/11/29/quarterly-noise-complaints-queens-community-board-10/). I was probably trying to solve a problem with the resolutions but do not recall now what exactly; but these posts are easier to fix since I can regenerate the html with the new links which are sequential - district_1.png, district_2.png, etc. Question for this part: is there a posts directory in WP where I can simply overwrite the files? In Blogger there wasn't (that I could find/access) and I had to copy-paste the code into the post editor window.

Comment: When I found the original image that you have used for illustration above (resoRatesTop6_2010to2018.png), I did notice that the resolution was a little smaller (around 300px less wide) than the WP version, but otherwise, things were pretty similar. Refer to -  `https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-s0OsiOYja18/XGSX31P1LJI/AAAAAAAAA7g/QLH0GVIghkobCvphLltxOfVrLVoplGVKwCLcBGAs/s0/resoRatesTop6_2010to2018.png` vs `https://datatellsme.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/resoRatesTop6_2010to2018.png`. Maybe Blogger editor was referencing the low-res variant of your uploaded images which has led to the confusion

Comment: TY - the WP resolution matches that of the source file. I re-uploaded & overwrote a few files to WP before I gave it up as too tedious. That is the high-res you are probably seeing. Blogger/Google was a big mistake. I didn't realize even the larger image files were downsampled in addition to new low-res images that Blogger created. I am going to try vector (.eps) images instead of raster. If they load fine on major devices I'm just going to search/replace all images and be done with it.

Comment: Just curious about one thing. In the Google Photos Settings (https://photos.google.com/settings) in your Google account, is __Original__ selected or is __High quality__ selected for the *Upload size for photos and videos* option?

Comment: Original - Full resolution that counts against my quota. What Google is doing is it respects your setting technically but in practical/effective terms, no. You have to click on the blurry image on a mobile to get the full resolution. And all images except the first one even on a desktop. I'd rather let the user zoom both text and image at the same time so you can read the text to better understand the graph. Rather than click back forth a dozen times to figure out what the various elements of a graph are.

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand your concern now. One more thing that I wanted to ask. Once you uploaded the image via the Blogger Editor, did you set the size as **Original size** or something else? Refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/toEeP.png

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at - I chose X-Large. 'Original size' would in some cases exceed theme borders and generally screw things up. I don't recall now but even with Original size, I think it would still do the downsample for mobiles routine. Otherwise I would have set the image size to fit in the theme window. Hard to recall - I struggled with images and tried a lot of things [on the fly.](https://nycstat.blogspot.com/2017/01/test-post.html) I do remember EPS files showed up fine on iOS & Mac but I made a mental not to check on Android/Windows/Linux etc

Comment: For issue related to images exceeding the post container when Original size was selected, adding the following CSS would resolve that `.post-body img{max-width:100%;padding: 0}a[imageanchor="1"]{margin:0 !important}` (So that this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcgSl.png becomes this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqXVc.png). For Mobile, due to using the default mobile theme, you didn't have any control over the code (aka any custom things you did on the desktop wouldn't show up in Mobile). Switching to the Custom Mobile theme via Settings (Theme > Gear Icon > Dropdown > Custom) would resolve that

Comment: Thanks. If I decide to go back to Blogger (never say never) I will keep your CSS in mind. Also FWIW, letting graphics exceed the container size was an aesthetic choice that grew out of tinkering with image size and placement - sort of mimics papers on a desk and tendency of people to offset the read pages slightly to the right as a place mark while they attend to something else.